# "IndexError: list index out of range" at Index 0

Tags: python

I am trying to reorganize some data from a csv file using the csv module and when I call `row[0]` it gives me this error `IndexError: list index out of range` even though it should not be out of the lists range given that I am calling Index 0.

This is a sample of what my data looks like in the csv file. It is only one column.

```
Caucasian
Black or African American
Caucasian
Asian or Pacific Islander
Caucasian,Hispanic or Latino,Native American or American Indian
Caucasian
Caucasian
Caucasian
Middle Eastern,Asian or Pacific Islander
Asian or Pacific Islander
```

Heres a sample of my code:

```
for row in csvReader:
    if row[0] == "Hispanic,Latino,or Spanish origin":
        print("")
    raceList = row[0].split(",")
    elif (len(raceList) > 1):
        csvWriter.writerow(["Mixed Race"])
    elif (row[0] == "African American"):
        csvWriter.writerow(["Black or African American"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a row is empty. This produces an empty list when the `csvReader` tries to read it, and empty lists don't even have index 0. First thing to do is confirm that this is happening by adding a print statement at the beginning of your `for` loop:

```
print(row)
```

and after running that, you should see `[]` printed just before you get the `IndexError`.

However, since it's a blank line, we probably don't care about skipping it. To skip the line, just use a `continue` statement to jump to the next iteration of the `for` loop:

```
if len(row) == 0:  # `if not row:` would also work, but this is somewhat more clear
    continue
```

or handle it differently, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much. That seemed to work. I checked to see if I had blanks in Excel since I've got more than 800 rows to comb through.